# How to 301 redirect pages "up" a page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm a newbie and I'm trying to figure out the proper 301 redirect for the following pages.  I hope I'm being clear here :)  In my .htaccess file, I want to redirect pages "up" one pages without having to do every page individually.

My original pages looked like the following:

```
www.doctors.com/skin/california/best-skin-doctors-california/
www.doctors.com/skin/california/best-skin-doctors-california/?page=1
www.doctors.com/skin/california/best-skin-doctors-california/?page=2
```

....etc. ....up to like /?page=33

and more categories and states, like:

```
 www.doctors.com/heart/new-york/best-heart-doctors-new-york/
 www.doctors.com/heart/new-york/best-heart-doctors-new-york/?page=1
 www.doctors.com/heart/new-york/best-heart-doctors-new-york/?page=2
```

...etc.   .....again up to like /?page=24

I've since changed the page structure to eliminate the long URLs...like this:

```
www.doctors.com/skin/california/
www.doctors.com/skin/california/?page=1
www.doctors.com/skin/california/?page=2
```

etc.....and similarly....

```
 www.doctors.com/heart/new-york/
 www.doctors.com/heart/new-york/?page=1
 www.doctors.com/heart/new-york/?page=2
```

etc.

How can I "bulk" redirect the original pages with the long URLs to the newer, shortened version in my .htaccess file?  Thank you very much for your time and consideration!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using mod_alias, you can simply add this in the .htaccess file in your document root:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([a-z\-]+)/([a-z\-]+)/[a-z\-]+/$ /$1/$2/
```

But if you need further restrictions on how the redirect works, you can use [Apache's mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) module. Taking a look at the `RewriteCond` directive, you can impose conditions on a rule and put everything in .htaccess. The main rule will look very similar to mod_alias' `RedirectMatch`. Example:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)/([a-z\-]+)/[a-z\-]+/$ /$1/$2/ [R=301,L]
```

In both cases, the query string (the page=3 part) is simply appended to the new target. Looking over the [different things you can do with `RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond), say if you wanted to exclude this rule when requests are made for something like `/images/` or `/themes/`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/themes/
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)/([a-z\-]+)/[a-z\-]+/$ /$1/$2/ [R=301,L]
```

So, if the request doesn't start with `/images/` **and** the request doesn't start with `/themes/`, then apply the rule. This example would make it so a request for http://host.com/themes/subSilver/magic-icons/ don't get redirected to http://host.com/themes/subSilver/.

Comment: The first one seems to be working great.  Thank you very much Jon!